# There is no Registered Eureka client instances. (JAVA11, Maven)

Tags: java, spring, maven, netflix-eureka

I'm working on Spring Cloud project using Java 11 and Maven.

I've try to register an Eureka client service with an Eureka Server. But there is no registered service showing on the Eureka dashboard.

I've been tried to search solution on the internet including Stackoverflow as well but there is no luck.

[image: ()]

Here is my dependencies of pom.xml in **Eureka** Project,

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And this is my properties of **Eureka** Project,

```
    server.port=8761
    spring.application.name=eureka-server

    eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
    eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
    eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
    eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    eureka.server.enableSelfPreservation=true

    logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
    logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF

    message=Eureka hello
```

And Here is my one of properties from Client Service (**auth-server**),

```
server.port=8001
spring.application.name=auth-server

#Eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
management.security.enabled=false
```

together with AuthServerApplication.java file,

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: what error you are getting while bringing up your auth-service. If it fails to register to Eureka server it should throw some error in the logs else if gets registered successfully, it will write the same in the logs. Please update the error log in your question.

Answer (score -1):

I have changed the version and it has started working for me.

<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>